# firstWithPredicate not accepting date

Tags: javascript, ios, ios-ui-automation

I working on UIAutomation for an app, and have a cells on a table view which has data and time as two separate elements.

Below is the code I am using to get a cell matching the date or time passed as predicate string.

```
var cell = tableView().cells().firstWithPredicate(date); (Eg: date is 3/5/12) OR
var cell = tableView().cells().firstWithPredicate(time); (Eg: time is 10:30 AM)
```

I even tried converting the predicates to string as below:

```
var cell = tableView().cells().firstWithPredicate(date.toString()); (Eg: date is 3/5/12) OR
var cell = tableView().cells().firstWithPredicate(time.toString()); (Eg: time is 10:30 AM)
```

But it seems its not able to find a matching cell. However if I pass some other text on the cell apart from date or time, I am getting the cell back.

Am I missing something here? Please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the value in variable, you can get that using its index as below,
`var cellDate = tableView().cells()[<index_of_cell_where_date_is_present>]` like
`var cellDate = tableView().cells()[2].name();` or
`var cellDate = tableView().cells()[2].value();` whichever is required.
Similarly you can use for time also.